# Sanitizing user input, is it safe?

Tags: php, security

I want to know the most secure way to sanitize data that is given to a PHP script, this is the function I have come up with, do you think that it's safe enough to use?

```
function santatizeName($data)
{
    $data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $data = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i','',$data); //Removes everything but letters.
    $data = ucfirst($data); //Capatilizes first letter.

    return $data;
}
```

Would love your feedback, new to PHP security.

Comment: What if a user's name includes hyphens or other language specific characters?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst not anymore it won't.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini My point exactly.

Comment: The very fact that a question is being asked indicates (to me) that **it is likely not "safe enough".** There are already a number of well-tested ways to "sanitize" or otherwise correctly used/consume data, so unless this is for a *Business Rule* (which should not preclude/be confused with sanitization!), then it plays a dubious role ..

Comment: Define 'safe'. What is unsafe about the string before you run your function on it?

Comment: @pst Could you link me to these 'well-tested ways' I always here people refer to them but never actually have any examples.

Comment: It kinda depends in what context you plan on using the data. I mean if you plan on using the returned data in say `system()` depending on your command it could be a problem to even allow alpha chars where a whitelist would be a better option. There is no silver bullet, you need to sanitize and validate on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Name validation has been discussed countless times. It's just not worth it because you *can't* if you want to retain all name possibilities.

Comment: @Supericy Well this data is going to be stored in a database and may be displayed on webpages after words, users might try to add javascript to this or html tags, or SQL code.

Comment: @GregValantine Well, *how* is the data being used? In an SQL query? Use placeholders. In HTML output? Use an escaping function (or better, templates/MVC with automatic escaping). In JSON? Use a serializer. In system? Don't use shell escapes and pray ..

Comment: Mr. O'Hara, Mrs. Smith-Meyer and maybe even Mr. Möller will all be very happy about the sanitized versions of their last names.

Comment: Don't write your own security controls! Reinventing the wheel when it comes to developing security controls for every web application or web service leads to wasted time and massive security holes. [OWASP Enterprise Security API](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/)

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos That's not *entirely* true, at least given Unicode and an accurate mapping to defined classes. Some Business Rules might make sense: e.g. 1) Must be >= 1 in length 2) Must not contain control or reserved characters 3) Must not begin/end with a "non word" character (i.e. whitespace; could be refined to exclude characters like hyphens or apostrophes) 4) Cannot contain more than one consecutive "whitespace" (could encompass characters like hyphens and apostrophes, but this is more of a gray area). Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 2):

The concept of input sanitation is actually futile on strings, given the business need of using all characters in most fields, especially in name fields (think Mr. O'Hara, Mrs. Smith-Meyer and Mr. Möller), and given the fact that almost any character is dangerous in some other context. You should look into properly escaping/encoding your string data whenever it changes context (such as when you put it into a database query, shell command, or input into dynamically generated HTML/CSS/JS/whatever). Use safe APIs for DB access, such as prepared statements, instead of constructing SQL by string concatenation.

That being said, you might find the [OWASP PHP filters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_PHP_Filters) or [OWASP ESAPI for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/) useful.

Comment: You linked me to 'OWASP PHP filters' but looking at there sanitization functions nothing seems to be different? The only problem I seem to have with my function is the " O'Hara " one as stated by @Daniel Roethlisberger

Comment: @GregValantine I linked to the OWASP code so you don't have to reinvent the wheel if you want to do input filtering. My main point is that the concept of input filtering does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to review the following php documentation regarding sanitization filters.

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

and

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://htmlpurifier.org/ although it's much more than sanitizing.